# Socket.io second server should connect when first one reconnect_failed

Tags: socket.io, connectivity

I got a scenario that i am implementing socket.io connectivity to push notifications to all clients,

```
    sockets = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");
       sockets.on("connection", function(socket){
            socket.on('connect',function(data){
             });
       socket.on('reconnect_failed',function(){
           console.log("reconnect_Failed");
               io.connect("http;//localhost:4000");
                 //Here i want to register a new socket when
                 // the first server is not able to reconnect
         });
      });
```

Please guide me to register when only first server is down. so that i can avoid the registering of second instance while running first server... Does this code helps. My Output is null not showing whether it is connected or not. First server is running fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo, `http;//`

That should do :

```
socket.on('reconnect_failed',function(){
           console.log("reconnect_Failed");
               io.connect("http://localhost:4000");
                 //Here i want to register a new socket when
                 // the first server is not able to reconnect
         });
      });
```

Comment: Please check the question. "Extending this question for another solution at client side." please guide me to register with any other way to work in same page

Comment: you can't change the question once it's answered, it completely defeats the purpose of this site. Please post your new question separately and I'll have a look at it ;)